# Count occurrences where two fields are equal

Tags: awk

Is it possible to write an awk one-liner which will compare two fields on the same line to see if they are equal, and output the number of lines where this is true?

I tried:

```
awk '$1==$2 { print($1 $2); }' foo1 | wc -l
```

I don't think this is correct.

Comment: it seems to work for me. why do you say not correct?

Comment: Very sorry, I had != instead of == running.

Comment: btw you can just print only one of the fields (e.g `print $1`) since you're just counting the lines..

Comment: Or print the whole line by just using `print`

Answer (score 6):

```
awk '$1 == $2 {n++}; END {print n}'
```